# Markdown: continue numbered list

Tags: markdown

In the following markdown code I want `item 3` to start with list number 3. But because of the code block in between markdown starts this list item as a new list. Is there any way to prevent that behaviour?

Desired output:

````
1. item 1
2. item 2

```
Code block
```

3. item 3
````

Produced output:

1. item 1
2. item 2

`Code block`

1. item 3

Comment: Here's the [correct solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22138846/1269037). The triple backticks in the Macmade's answer actually just produce a `<code>` HTML element with newlines in it, which is not syntax-highlightable, and has an extra blank line above visibly highlighted as code.

Comment: If you're really desperate, you could look up the HTML character codes for the numbers you wish to use (and for every subsequent item)... as in `&#50;&#57;. this is list item number 29`. This may not work in all markdown parsers though.

Answer (score 980, accepted):

Use four spaces to indent content between bullet points

````
1. item 1
2. item 2

    ```
    Code block
    ```
3. item 3
````

Produces:

1. item 1
2. item 2

   `Code block`
3. item 3

Comment: Yes, indentation makes it clear to the parser that the code block belongs to the list item 2. Otherwise, it's just a normal paragraph, and will end the list.

Comment: I believe I have found a slightly [more elegant solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22138846/1269037). The triple backticks actually just produce a `<code>` with newlines in it, which is not syntax-highlightable, and show a blank newline above.

Comment: It even works with escaped backticks in the code block! I can't believe, though, that there is no "normal" way of doing this, without hacks.

Comment: But ... what if you don't want indentation there?  Markdown has no solution, as far as I know.  It's often a natural thing to start a list, then stop and provide some text that's a meta comment about the list--what we just did, and what's coming next--without the text being, logically, part of the list--and then continue the list.  Markdown does not want us to do that. It's a form of thought that Markdown does not want people to express--that Markdown does not know how to express, that Markdown thinks is too ... free. Tools should follow thought.  Sigh.  I could write in HTML, or make PDFs.

Comment: Note that I had to use 4 spaces and couldn't use tab in my specific case for this to work.

Comment: A link related to this question: https://gist.github.com/clintel/1155906#file-gistfile1-md

Comment: Doesn't seem to work at all for me. I have a simple numbered list, and indented and new-lined as shown above. Still restarts at 1.

Comment: In the few Markdown editors that I've tried (Bitbucket, Tumblr), this doesn't work -- it renders inline code instead of a properly indented code block.

Comment: @10basetom for Bitbucket, I've found that intenting the code twice and removing the triple ticks more or less accomplishes the desired effect. The only issue is that then you can't specify language formatting, but apparently that's not part of the "official" markdown implementation anyhow.

Comment: Thanks, this work well on GitLab too! But the Eclipse Markdown Previewer is buggy (Oxygen Release v4.7.0).

Comment: Works in wordpress

Comment: In IntelliJ it makes a difference how many blank lines are at the bottom of each numbered block. If you leave 2 blank lines, it restarts numbering; leave only one and it continues.

Comment: Same issue with standard HTML ol elements.

Comment: good solution, but you only have to write "1." , "1." , "1." , "1." ... (never "2.","3.", "4."....)

Answer (score 64):

As an extension to existing answers. For those trying to continue a numbered list after something other than a code block. For example a second paragraph. Just indent the second paragraph by at least 1 space.

**Markdown:**

```
1. one
2. two

 three
3. four
```

**Output:**

1. one
2. two

   three
3. four

Comment: Sweet! I had a series of pseudo code blocks and MathJax equations. This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Doesn't work on GitHub Wiki. Adding more spaces will at least make the numbering the same type as the numbers above tho. :rofl:

Comment: @ChaimEliyah Thats because im 99% sure the wiki doesn't use GitHub flavoured markdown (im sure I've come across this curiosity previously)

Comment: This will also take care of situations where you have a list entry containing some text, some code, and finally more text before the end of the list entry.

Comment: It's not working for me on IntelliJ but I don't know if it'll work on GitHub.

Comment: It works at top level in GitLab/CommonMark, but not for nested lists

Comment: This answer worked for me for a list with inline images, whereas the accepted answer did not.

Answer (score 46):

Notice how in Macmade's solution, you can see an extra line of code above the "Code block".

Here are two better solutions:

1. Indent the code block by an extra 4 spaces (so usually 8, in this nested list example, 12). This will put the code in a `<pre>` element. On SO, you can even specify [syntax highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) with a
   `<!-- language: lang-js -->` indented by 4 spaces (+1 here due to the nested list).

   1. item 1
   2. item 2

      ```js
      Code.block('JavaScript', maybe)?
      ```
   3. item 3
2. Or, just put the Code block within backticks and indent by 4 spaces (here, 1 extra because of the nested list). You'll get a regular indented text paragraph, with a `<code>` element inside it. This one you can't syntax-highlight:

   1. item 1
   2. item 2

      `Code block`
   3. item 3

Note: you can click "edit" on this answer to see the underlying Markdown code. No need to save ;)

Comment: This is a solution for this particular problem, but it's not a general solution to the problem of restarting a Markdown list at the next number after some intervening text.  It appears that there is no way to do this, which drives me crazy.  Everything else about Markdown is great.

Comment: @Mars as you can see from [DavidT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36337068/5179394), the general solution is to indent the text with any number of spaces. For instance, adding one space instead of four will allow you to insert any intervening text without having to create a code block.

Answer (score 37):

Macmade's solution doesn't work for me anymore on my Jekyll instance on Github Pages anymore but I found [this solution](https://github.com/gettalong/kramdown/issues/211#issuecomment-256508905) on an issue for the kramdown github repo. For OP's example it would look like this:

````
1. item 1
2. item 2

```
Code block
```

{:start="3"}
3. item 3
````

Solved my issues handily.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work with GitHub readme files. :(

Comment: Was excited to read this, but in my Fastpages (Jekyll Github Pages) blog that uses kramdown, that start code is simply ignored.  I suspect it gets mangled by Liquid or nbdev.

Answer (score 27):

If you use tab to indent the code block it will shape the entire block into one line. To avoid this you need to use html ordered list.

1. item 1
2. item 2

Code block

```
<ol start="3">
  <li>item 3</li>
  <li>item 4</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Works for me with markdown on the "dev.to" dev blog platform, thanks.

Answer (score 23):

If you happen to be using the Ruby gem [redcarpet](https://rubygems.org/gems/redcarpet) to render Markdown, you may still have this problem.

You can escape the numbering, and redcarpet will happily ignore any special meaning:

```
1\. Some heading

text text
text text

text text

2\. Some other heading

blah blah

more blah blah
```

Comment: This is the only solution works for me: multiple line code blocks in ordered list, and the code still formatted correctly with newlines, and works on Github.

Comment: Just opened a [PR](https://github.com/vmg/redcarpet/pull/741) with redcarpet to support broken-up ordered lists. Fingers crossed.

Answer (score 8):

Source:

````
<span>1.</span> item 1<br/>
<span>2.</span> item 2
```
Code block
```
<span>3.</span> item 3
````

Result:

1. item 1
2. item 2

```
Code block
```

3. item 3

Comment: this is HTML, not Markdown

Answer (score 8):

When you indent with 4 spaces, you never have to increment your numbers from "1." to "2." to "3."...

**Markdown**:

````
1. item 1
1. item 2

    ```
    Code block
    ```
1. item 3
````

**Produces this output**:

````
1. item 1
2. item 2

    ```
    Code block
    ```
3. item 3
````

Answer (score 7):

In [CommonMark Spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#lists) has a rules about this

```
1. foo
2. bar
3) baz
```

Generate this HTML

```
<ol>
<li>foo</li>
<li>bar</li>
</ol>
<ol start="3">
<li>baz</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer by far.

Answer (score 5):

If you don't want the lines in between the list items to be indented, like user Mars mentioned in his comment, you can use `pandoc`'s `example_lists` feature. From their [docs](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#pandocs-markdown):

```
(@)  My first example will be numbered (1).
(@)  My second example will be numbered (2).

Explanation of examples.

(@)  My third example will be numbered (3).
```

Comment: This is the most universal solution to this problem. There's no need to indent and It even works if you have headings between the list elements.

Comment: The `(@)` corresponds to a global continuing list (so there can be only one. Using `pandoc`'s `startnum` extension you can start an ordered list with the number you want and it just works.

Comment: This gets rendered as a literal '(@)' by kramdown, nothing more.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to add a backslash (`\`) before the period (`1\. item 1`), which [disables the list auto-numbering](https://salferrarello.com/markdown-avoid-auto-numbering/). *Note: this will remove left side indentation.*

1. item 1

```py
def call_of_duty()
   return press_f()
```

3. item 3

```py
print("fus ro dah")
```

7. item 7

```py
print("Omae Wa Mou Shindeiru")
```

10. item 10

---

From the link source:

```
3\. Put on shoes
2\. Open door
1\. Step outside

renders

3. Put on shoes
2. Open door
1. Step outside
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem on Github separating the indented sub-block with a newline, for instance, you write the item 1, then hit enter twice (like if it was a new paragraph), indent the block and write what you want (a block of code, text, etc). More information on [Markdown lists](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#lists) and [Markdown line breaks](https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet#lines).

#### Example:

1. item one
2. item two

   `this block acts as a new paragraph, above there is a blank line`
3. item three

   `some other code`
4. item four

Comment: This also applies in GatsbyJS

Answer (score 2):

Note that there are also a number of extensions available that will fix this behaviour for specific contexts of Markdown use.

For example, **[sane_lists](https://python-markdown.github.io/extensions/sane_lists/)** extension of python-markdown (used in mkdocs, for example), will recognize numbers used in Markdown lists. You just need to enable this extension `markdown.markdown(some_text, extensions=['sane_lists'])`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have text aligned to preceding list item but avoid having "big" line break, use two spaces at the end of a list item and indent the text with some spaces.

Source: (dots are spaces ;-) of course)

```
1.·item1··
····This is some text
2.item2
```

Result:

1. item1
   This is some text
2. item2

Comment: Thanks--although this is not strictly speaking an answer to the original question, it is an answer to what some people want to know when they find their way to this page.

Answer (score 1):

Put the list numbers in parentheses instead of followed by a period.

(1) item 1
(2) item 2

`code block`

(3) item 3

Comment: This destroys the `<ol>` and `<li>` elems and instead just wraps them in `<p>` tags.  Additionally, you literally get `(1)`.

Comment: I think that was the intent.

Comment: It keeps `<ol>` and `<li>` for me (using Pandoc via Hakyl)l. It seems to be the switch from `x.` form to `(x)` form that causes a new `start` parameter to be inserted into the `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very simple: don't use the dot space.

e.g.

```
1.apple

2.banana

3.cherry

4.drone
```

which produces:

1.apple

2.banana

3.cherry

4.drone

Comment: This doesn't seems like a "very simple" solution to me, lets say you want to delete the 2nd item ( banana) now you have to rename all the items below it isn't it?

Comment: No, since it markdown, it will solve it for you and do an ordered list: https://carpentries-incubator.github.io/markdown-intro/06-lists/index.html