# Continue Enumeration after Code Block?

Tags: markdown

I have a Markdown enumeration:

1. sdsdf
2. sdfsdf

`some code`

3. sdfsdf

The `3.` is shown as one because of the code block.

How can I insert a code block in one of the enumeration steps and let the enumeration counter continue correctly after the counter?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Markdown: continue numbered list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088955/markdown-continue-numbered-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indent the code block by four additional spaces to show that it's part of the preceding list item:

```
1. sdsdf
1. sdfsdf

        function foo() {
            // do something
        }

1. sdfsdf
```

The extra four spaces [are required to include the code block in the list item](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list):

> To put a code block within a list item, the code block needs to be indented *twice* - 8 spaces or two tabs:
>
> ```
> * A list item with a code block:
>
>         <code goes here>
> ```

Comment: In this case the intentions of the code block are gone.

Comment: @stephan1001, your comment is unclear. What does "the intentions of the code block are gone" mean?

Comment: @stephan1001, not at all. Just indent all code lines by an additional four spaces. See my updated answer.

Comment: Yes I know but why do I need the additional four spaces?

Comment: @stephan1001, so the code block is included in the list item. It's part of the spec. I've updated my answer again.

Comment: This is not the solution I want. I knew this before. I do not won't to loose the indents and I do not want to add spaces in every line.