# Display code sample with ">" character as part of a bullet paragraph in markdown

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I would like to display the following

```
$ env/bin/python
>>>import requests
>>> requests.get('http://dabapps.com')
<Response [200]>
```

as a code sample within a bullet paragraph for Github styled markdown. How do I do it?

Comment: Indent it a whole bunch. I don't know how much, but keep indenting in 4 space increments until it works :p

Comment: @Alexander Thanks for the idea. After trying, I discovered that I needed a blank line with 4 leading space, above and below my code sample. Also I needed 4 spaces plus 1xTab for each line of the code sample. The 4 leading spaces is to align the text in the code sample with the text in the bullet paragraph. The 1xTab then created the code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Legend:

- ---- denotes 4x leading spaces.
- 1xTab denotes pressing the Tab key once.
- ----1xTab denotes 4x leading spaces plus pressing the Tab key once.

The syntax format I found to work and implement in Remarkable:

```
1. 1st Bullet point: 
----    
----1xTab$ env/bin/pip install requests
----
----1st Bullet point paragraph
----    
----1xTab$ env/bin/python
----1xTab>>>import requests
----1xTab>>> requests.get('http://dabapps.com')
----1xTab<Response [200]>
----        
2. 2nd Bullet point:
```

Result:

1. 1st Bullet point:

   ```
   $ env/bin/pip install requests
   ```

   1st Bullet point paragraph

   ```
   $ env/bin/python
   >>>import requests
   >>> requests.get('http://dabapps.com')
   <Response [200]>
   ```
2. 2nd Bullet point:

Comment: BTW, as far as markdown is concern, spaces and tabs are the same. The indentation could have been entirely spaces, depending on which your source code to have

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using a [fenced code block](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-and-highlighting-code-blocks/):

````
* Bullet list item 1
* Bullet list item 2
  ```
  $ env/bin/python
  >>>import requests
  >>> requests.get('http://dabapps.com')
  <Response [200]>
  ```
* Bullet list item 3
````

See below for markdown preview in [Atom](https://atom.io/):

[image]

And here it is in [Remarkable](https://jonschlinkert.github.io/remarkable/demo/):

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I tried it in "Remarkable" but strangely it did not work. Don't know why it did not work. :(

Comment: Hi @SunBear I just tried it with this online [Remarkable demo](https://jonschlinkert.github.io/remarkable/demo/) and it worked for me just fine...

Comment: Related: [Markdown: continue numbered list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18088955/markdown-continue-numbered-list)

Comment: I am using Remarkable ver. 1.87 app. It's 'Help-->Github' had directed me to this other [homepage](https://github.com/jamiemcg/Remarkable). This app and version is giving me the issue.The use of **Indented code** and **Fence**  should both work. Not sure why the 'fence' approach did not work in this app. :(  Really appreciate the links you had provided. ;)